# What are the 50 words on the Wechsler Test of Adult Reading (WTAR)?

Tags: intelligence, neuropsychology

I recently took part in a study that asked me to read 50 words that were spelled differently than they were pronouced, some more commonly used than others. Does anyone know where I could find this list? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wechsler_Test_of_Adult_Reading

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for specific test items.

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr - that happens to be asked for quite often here, is it not?

Comment: @AliceD http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/982/should-we-discourage-divulging-the-mechanics-of-neuropsychological-tests-here

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr - am mobile. Perhaps later.

Comment: @AliceD No problem. It might be useful to know that after users have joined the chat once, @ notifications will work and send a browser link to the chat in the SE mobile app.